# SPARQL avoid cross products of multiple output variables

Tags: sparql

Suppose that I want to get all the rdfs:subclassOf+ for both dbo:Person, and dbo:Politician in one query.

The following query I have right now outputs the cartesian product of both type1 and type2, which I do not want. Is there a way for me to prevent this? (I want the behavior to be as if I am asking two separate queries).

```
select ?type1 ?type where {
    dbo:Politician rdfs:subClassOf+ ?type1.
    dbo:Person rdfs:subClassOf+ ?type2.
}
```

Comment: [`UNION`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#alternatives)?

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `select distinct ?sup where {
    VALUES ?sub {dbo:Politician dbo:Person} ?sub rdfs:subClassOf+ ?sup.
}`